# Accessing object in array recreating object?

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface

I am making a console game and I am making a map. The map is an array of vectors. The vectors contain the characters that I am printing to the console. My code:

"Window.h"

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Row {
public:
    std::vector<char> row;
    int id;
    Row();
    void printRow();
    void resetRow();
    void insertStringIntoRow(std::string toInsert, int startIndex);
    std::vector<char> getRow() {
        return row;
    }
};

class Window {
public:
    void showMap();
    void writeToMap(std::string stringToInsert, int rowNum, int startIndex);
    void writeInRectangle(std::string stringToWrite, int rowNum, int startIndex);
    void setCursorToPosition(int x, int y);
    void resetMap();
    Row getRowAt(int index);
};

void initColors();
void setWindow(Window windowToSet);
Window getGameWindow();
```

"Window.cpp"

```
#include "Window.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinBase.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "color.h"

using namespace eku;

Row map[25];

//Class Window
void Window::showMap() {
    setCursorToPosition(0, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        getRowAt(i).printRow();
    }
}

void Window::writeToMap(std::string stringToInsert, int rowNum, int startIndex) {
    Row r = getRowAt(rowNum);
    r.insertStringIntoRow(stringToInsert, startIndex);
}

void Window::writeInRectangle(std::string stringToWrite, int rowNum, int startIndex) {
    if (startIndex != 0) {
        std::string topbar = "~";
        for (int i = 0; i < stringToWrite.length() + 2; i++) {
            topbar += ' ';
        }
        topbar += '^';
        getRowAt(rowNum - 1).insertStringIntoRow(topbar, startIndex - 1);
    }

    std::string toInsert = "~ ^" + stringToWrite + "~ ^";
    getRowAt(rowNum).insertStringIntoRow(toInsert, startIndex - 1);

    if (startIndex != 25) {
        std::string bottombar = "~";
        for (int i = 0; i < stringToWrite.length() + 2; i++) {
            bottombar += ' ';
        }
        bottombar += '^';
        getRowAt(rowNum + 1).insertStringIntoRow(bottombar, startIndex - 1);
    }
}

void Window::setCursorToPosition(int x, int y) {
    HANDLE hOut;
    COORD Position;
    hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    Position.X = x;
    Position.Y = y;

    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hOut, Position);
}

void Window::resetMap() {
    for (Row row : map) {
        row.resetRow();
    }
}

Row Window::getRowAt(int index)
{
    return map[index];
}

//Class Row
const char WHITEBACKCOL = '~';
const char DEFCOL = '^';

int i = 0;

Row::Row() {
    row.resize(80, ' ');
    id = i;
    i++;
}

void Row::printRow() {
    for (int i = 0; i < row.size(); i++) {
        switch (row[i]) {
        case WHITEBACKCOL:
            setcolor(black, white);
        case DEFCOL:
            setcolor(white, black);
        default:
            std::cout << row[i];
        }
    }
}

void Row::resetRow() {
    row.resize(80);
    for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++) {
        row[i] = ' ';
    }
}

void Row::insertStringIntoRow(std::string toInsert, int startIndex) {
    int endIndex = (startIndex + toInsert.length());
    int stringPos = 0;
    for (int i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++) {
        if (i < row.size() - 1) {
            row.at(i) = toInsert[stringPos];
        }
        else {
            row.push_back(toInsert[stringPos]);
        }
        stringPos++;
    }
}
Window defWindow;

void initColors() {
    concolinit();
    setcolor(white, black);
}

void setWindow(Window windowToSet) {
    defWindow = windowToSet;
}

Window getGameWindow() {
    return defWindow;
}
```

"Main.cpp"

```
#include <iostream>
#include "GameEngine.h"
#include "Window.h"

int main() {
    setWindow(Window());
    initColors();

    getGameWindow().writeInRectangle("Hia", 1, 10);

    getGameWindow().showMap();
}
```

Whenever I call `showMap()` all I get is a blank console. It seems to be only printing the default map of spaces instead of the text I entered. I also tried using just `printRow()` to print the single rows that I edited but they also showed only spaces.
I was able view changes to the vector row in the `insertStringIntoRow()` method but then even though the changes should there they didn't show anywhere else. It almost seems like my `Row` object is being created every time I access it. I am new to C++ so any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you getting output as spaces or WHITEBACKCOL or DEFCOL .

Comment: Yes, row created in writeToMap is a temporary that gets discarded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function is being used incorrectly.  Warning signs are that it is non-const, yet used as an accessor.  It returns a copy of the vector, not a reference.

```
std::vector<char> getRow() {
    return row;
}
```

The way you are calling it, you are expecting it to modify the row in-place, but all you are actually doing is modifying a copy of the row, which is then immediately discarded.  Example:

```
getRowAt(rowNum).insertStringIntoRow(toInsert, startIndex - 1);
```

The easy fix for this behaviour is to return a reference from `getRow()`:

```
std::vector<char> & getRow() {
    return row;
}
```

The other thing to fix is where you assign this to a temporary variable instead of using it inline.  In that case, you can make the temporary a reference:

```
Row & r = getRowAt(rowNum);
r.insertStringIntoRow(stringToInsert, startIndex);
```

---

The *correct* way to implement this is to *also* provide a const-version, so that it can still be called on const objects where the caller does not want to modify it.

```
const std::vector<char> & getRow() const {
    return row;
}
```

I've only put this extra bit in here because it is good practice, but you should not do it in this program.  It would clutter your code which is already full of worse practices =)

Comment: It worked! Thanks. I come from Java so this concept is new to me.

Answer (score 0):

send a reference to writeToMap() instead of variables.
This will make changes to the original map objects instead of copy-variables.